# ESP32 - HardwareSerial 110 BaudRate

Tags: arduino, serial

Não consigo fazer a leitura de Serial em baudrate 110. Tentei algumas alternativas de alteração de clock do processador, mas não funcionou.

Alguém tem alguma ideia ou sugestão do que fazer?

Obrigado.

```
#define SSUSerial Serial1
#define RXD1 5
#define TXD1 18

char dataSSU[255];

void setup()
{

  setCpuFrequencyMhz(80);


  pinMode(SSerialTxControl, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit); // Init Transceiver

  // Start the software serial port, to another device
  RS485Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
  SSUSerial.begin(110, SERIAL_8N1, RXD1, TXD1);
  RS485Serial.setRxBufferSize(512);
  SSUSerial.setRxBufferSize(512);

  RS485Serial.println(F_CPU);
  RS485Serial.println(getCpuFrequencyMhz());

}

void loop()
{

  while (true)
  {
    digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit); // Disable RS485 Transmit
    if (int bytes = SSUSerial.available())                     //Look for data from other Arduino
    {
        RS485Serial.printf("Detected bytes in serial is %lu\n", bytes);
        while (SSUSerial.available())
        {
          delay(1);
          char caractereSSU = SSUSerial.read();
          dataSSU[countSSU] = caractereSSU;
          countSSU++;

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < countSSU; i++){
          RS485Serial.print("[");
          RS485Serial.print(int(dataSSU[i]), DEC);
          RS485Serial.print("]");
        }
        dataSSUComplete = true;
      }
      String conteudo = "";
      char caractere;
      int count = 0;

      RS485Serial.print("Numero de Bytes Recebidos:");
      RS485Serial.print(countSSU);
      RS485Serial.println("<- Recebido pelo SSU");
      RS485Serial.flush();
      digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive); // Disable RS485 Transmit

      countSSU = 0;
    }
  }
```